# Search SQL with Date Range and Checkbox

Tags: php, sql, search, checkbox

I've been trying to develop a code where I have a form to search SQL tables according to date ranges and a checkbox status.

I already have worked out the search query for the dates, but I haven't been able to make it work with the checkbox. I would like to combine both features in one search but I can't figure it out.

For ex: Search between "**01/01/2012**" and "**12/31/2012**" where status is "DONE! **(Checkbox=Checked)**".

Here is the code I'm using to do the search:

The Form

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top:15px;">
                    <span>From&nbsp:</span>
                    <input type = "date" name = "OLD">
                    To:
                    <input type = "date" name = "NEW">
                    Status:
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Status' value='DONE'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top:15px;">
                    <button type = "submit" name = "search" value = "Search" class="button orange">Search</button>
                    <button type = "reset" value = "Clear" class="button orange">Reset</button>
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

The PHP

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['search']))
    {
    ?>

    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        $OLD = trim($_POST['from']);
        $NEW = trim($_POST['to']);

        $connection = mysql_pconnect("HOST", "USER", "PASS") or die("Connection failed. ".myslq_error());
        mysql_select_db("DATABASENAME") or die("Unable to select db. ".mysql_error());
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date >= '$OLD' AND Date <= '$NEW' ORDER BY date ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<table class='table' id='SearchResult' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
            echo "<tr class='rowa'><b>";
                echo "<td class='col1 cell'>Name</td>";
                echo "<td class='col2 cell'>Last Name</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        while($record = mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {   
        echo "<table class='table' id='SearchResult' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
            echo "<tr class='rowb'>";
                echo "<td class='col1 cell'>".$record->Name."</td>";
                echo "<td class='col2 cell'>".$record->LastName."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";       
        echo "</table>";
        }       
    }
?>
```

Who can lead me in the right way to accomplish this?! Thanks a lot!

Comment: there is no status check in $query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
else
{
    $OLD = trim($_POST['from']);
    $NEW = trim($_POST['to']);
    $status = isset($_POST['Status']) ? "AND status = 'DONE' " :"AND status = 'NOT DONE' ";

    $connection = mysql_pconnect("HOST", "USER", "PASS") or die("Connection failed. ".myslq_error());
    mysql_select_db("DATABASENAME") or die("Unable to select db. ".mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date >= '$OLD' AND Date <= '$NEW' ".$status."ORDER BY date ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This made part of it to work! **Awesome!** The issue is that when the checkbox IS NOT checked the search stills showing both status, DONE and NOT DONE. Is there anyway to make the search show only those that ARE NOT DONE when the checkbox IS NOT check? **Your answer lead me pretty well to where I wanted! Thanks a lot!**

Comment: Great! It kinda does what I was trying to achieve! It's definitely the starting point to do what I wanted. Thanks  a lot @sephoy08

Answer (score 0):

I think the query composition must be something like that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 "
if ($_POST['MyCheckbox']=="checked")
  $query = $query . " and Date >= '$OLD' AND Date <= '$NEW' ORDER BY date ASC";
```